# I am not able to play DRM protected dash vidoes on any linux vm machine but same code is working on other shared hosting apache server

Tags: apache, video.js, drm, dash.js, shaka

Note: The videos url is signed with licence key and required data.
Same code is working inside the xampp apache server and shared hosting but not working on linux vm machine like ec2 , local ubuntu.

Console Error is :

```
IndexedDB.install
input_event.js:21 InputEvent.install
mathround.js:20 mathRound.install
mediasource.js:22 MediaSource.install
mediasource.js:76 Using native MSE as-is.
video_play_promise.js:21 VideoPlayPromise.install
vttcue.js:22 Using native VTTCue.
index.js:42 EmeEncryptionSchemePolyfill: EME not found
index.js:251 McEncryptionSchemePolyfill: Waiting to detect encryptionScheme support.
patchedmediakeys_nop.js:31 EME not available.
ams.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
microsoft.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
player.js:567 The walker saw an error:
(anonymous) @ player.js:567
player.js:569 Error Code: 6001
(anonymous) @ player.js:569
```

Complete html code is:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples/blob/master/src/shaka/index.html

The same console is not appearing on shared hosting apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, It is because of ssl configurations on server. To use DRM protected content we need to use a secure connection on live server.